# No xauth data; using fake authentication. Unable to display remote windows

Tags: ssh, x11, osx

Whenever  I try to `ssh -X` or `-Y` into a remote Linux server from my Mac (OSX Mavericks) machine, I get the same message:

> "Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11
>   forwarding."

I have tried several ideas that I found on SO threads, e.g. adding the following

```
Host *
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

in my `.ssh/config` file (which is equivalent to always doing `ssh -Y`), deleting the `.Xauthority` file in the server, etc.

Why does this happen?

Most importantly, when I try to open a remote window (e.g. using `ssh -Y`, and then opening a plot in Python), I get the following message:

```
Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: xxx.yyy.net
: Fatal IO error: client killed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have known better, but OS X does [not come](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5293) with an X server. You need to install your own. Once you install [XQuartz](https://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/), you can restart and the problem goes away.